# How do you make RDLC Fixed position footer

Tags: sql-server-2008, rdlc

My application is printing checks.  In the client's paper stock, the "check" itself is at the bottom 3rd of an 8.5x11in sheet.  The details that make up the check are on the top 2/3 of the sheet.

Now if I'm printing multiple checks in one go, I need the check to be essentially the page footer for my .rdlc, but that page footer must start at exactly the same vertical position on every page regardless of how many detail items are on the upper 2/3.

How is this accomplished with RDLC reports?  I can easily solve the problem when the check is on the top 2/3 of the page because the table does not affect it's positioning.  This one has me stumped.

If it helps, I am on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Basically could use the page footer option (instead of table footer) in RDLC and put ReportItems! formulas in there.  That worked fine for what I needed to do.